# What is the distinction between "nombrar" and "llamar"?

Tags: diferencias-entre-palabras

Recently reading the twitter feed of the Spanish meteorological agency AEMET I notice mention of the naming of an approaching storm which became borrasca Isaack. There is a helpful [graphic](https://twitter.com/AEMET_Esp/status/1623278304374538248) explaining how to tell whether it fulfils the criteria to be named.

If you have asked me before I saw the thread what the Spanish word for to call something by some name I would have said it was llamar and the [DLE entry](https://dle.rae.es/llamar?m=form) confirms that among many other things it carries that meaning. But we also have [nombrar](https://dle.rae.es/nombrar?m=form) which along with nombramiento is used in the thread which drew my attention.

So what is the difference in usage? Is nombrar more formal?

Comment: If you look up both in the RAE, you will see they can have the same meaning. Anyway, to call and give a name to something are different in English too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use "llamar", "nombrar", "denominar" or "designar" to mean "give sth a name". Also, "dar/asignar un nombre".

That said, "llamar" is the least formal of all and would not be a clear word to mean "give sth **a name**" when used without the name. We could only use it when the name is asked or provided:

- ¿**Cómo** llamaremos a la borrasca? / La llamaremos **Gloria**.
- ¿**Cómo** se llama la borrasca? / Se llama **Gloria**.

What calls my attention is the use of "nombramiento" to refer to the giving of a name. I'd only use it to mean "appointment (to a certain position or office)". I would have used "asignación de un nombre" or "denominación". However, "nombramiento" might be meteorological jargon.

Answer (score 1):

Las borrascas se nombran con antelación, se les dan nombres anticipadamente.

Las borrascas tienen nombre con antelación, pero no se les "llama" con antelación, que significaría otra cosa.

¿Cómo se llamarán las borrascas? Marta, Rita e Isaack. (¿Cómo nombro a las borrascas, qué nombre recibirán, si tengo después que llamarlas o dirigirme a ellas? Marta, Rita e Isaack.)

La borrasca tiene un nombre que es Isaack.

¿Cómo se llama la borrasca? Isaack. (¿Cuál es el nombre de la borrasca si tengo que llamarla? Isaack.)

Las cosas tienen un nombre y se les llama por su nombre, se nombran primero para saber como llamarlas después.

---

¿Cuál es tu nombre? Pedro. (¿Cómo fuiste nombrado? Pedro)

¿Cómo te llamas? Pedro. (¿Cómo te nombro si tengo que llamarte o dirigirme a ti? Pedro.)

---

¿Cuál es el nombre del objeto que sirve para telefonear? Teléfono.

¿Cómo se llama el objeto que sirve para telefonear? Teléfono. (¿Cómo nombro o que nombre digo, si tengo que llamar o dirigirme al objeto que sirve para telefonear? Teléfono.)

---

(Antes) Se nombra para distinguir a las personas, los animales, las cosas y otros elementos.

(Después) Se llaman con el nombre que recibieron para dirigirse a ellas.